# HTML5 video streaming very slow

Tags: html5-video

On my homepage there is a video file. While single user click on site(www.rollcall.co.in) that video running very well. But When Multiple  user come at my site and that time video streaming getting very slow. I dont know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Where are the site and the video hosted? Sounds like you have an issue with bandwidth.

Comment: thnkx.. But I solved this problem. Actually there is no issue with bandwith. It's moov atom is at last index so because of that  getting problem.